# Rails - link views new.mobile.erb _new.mobile.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

In my application view (**application.mobile.erb**) I have `<%= render 'account_sessions/new'>`. This calls to `account_sessions/_new.mobile.erb`.

I don't want to kept two copies of the same file. Is there a way to just to kept one copy? For example have **_new.mobile.erb** refer to **new.mobile.erb**. Or have `<%= render 'account_sessions/new'>` reference to **new.mobile.erb** not **_new.mobile.erb**

I have an **account_sessions** controller. But I don't know what to do so render will go to **new.mobile.erb**.

Comment: Try to write like this ` <%= render :file => 'account_sessions/new'>`

Answer (score 0):

Please, respond to the mobile request with the same template and do not distiguish between mobile and "normal" request.